# How do I cite one technical report from a project collection?

Tags: citations

My group are working individually on different aspects of the same research project. We will releasing our individual papers as technical reports.

It seems to be a common courtesy when publishing a paper to include your own citation. How do you cite a technical report so that it is clear that it is part of a collection (a single project)?

I was thinking of filling in the project name in the "journal" field so it would end up something like:

```
Surname, N. (2015) "My Paper" in Our Project, Article 4
```

But that seems to be abusing the semantics of the journal field. Is there a standard way to do this?

Comment: Will the reports be placed online in any archival manner?

Comment: @jakebeal see comment to bill barth below

Answer (score 1):

Some departments or institutes have their own technical report series that are published online much like a journal. If yours is like this, then you should be able to come up with a citation format that reflects it. How are your tech reports published and archived?

Comment: We are creating our own mini-website for the project under the department domain. Papers are optionally archived by the department on a publications website, but this is largely an adhoc affair (technical reports are not consistently numbered etc).

Comment: hmmm, how about "My Paper (Our Project)", Technical report, Department of Institution - cite as a generic technical report, just append the project name to the paper name?

Comment: You should look to the citation style instructions for technical reports for the venue where you plan to publish. Pretty much every style guide has a citation format for technical reports. It's best not to hijack a journal format if a tech report style is available.